# Struts 2 - accessing static member value. Seems to ignore 'struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess' value in struts.properties and struts.xml file

Tags: jsp, static, struts2, ognl, members

I'm trying to access a static member value in JSP as follows:
`"@package.subPackage.ClassName@STATIC_MEMBER"`

STATIC_MEMBER is declared as `public static final String` with a value assigned and class has public scope. My struts.properties (placed under webapps\appName\WEB-INF\classes folder) has `struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess=true` entry. But, Struts seems to ignore `struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess=true` entry in struts.properties.

I had followed same above steps in another project and it's working perfectly fine.

Notes:
1. I had cross-checked full package, class and STATIC_MEMBER name for correctness.
2. There are no errors / exceptions on page.
3. Same JSP is able to access member value from Action class (`<s:property value="actionMember"/>`).
4. I tried accessing static members from other class but, does not work.
5. I had tried deleting struts.properties file and making an entry in struts.xml file, after `<struts>` tag, as :
   `<constant name="struts.struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true" />`. Did a 
   re-start and re-tried. But, does not work.
6. I had re-build, re-deployed and re-started server after deleting web app and it's cache (work folder) from server but, didn't work.

Environment: Java 1.6, Struts 2.1, Tomcat 6.0 @ Windows XP 2002

Please help.
Thanks much in advance!

--------------------CODE UPDATE-------------------------------

**CLASS**

```
package package1.subPackage1;

public class FooClassName {
   public static final int INVALID_LOGIN = 0;   
}
```

**struts.properties**
`struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess=true`

**JSP**
`<s:if test="errorType == @package1.subPackage1.FooClassName@INVALID_LOGIN">
    some code here
</s:if>`

**Action class**:
1. `private int errorType;`
2. has respective getter and setter for `errorType`

It's not even printing the value, tried:
`<s:property value="@package1.subPackage1.FooClassName@INVALID_LOGIN"/>`

Comment: Try this <s:property value="@java.util.Calendar@DAY_OF_WEEK"/>, If it's working then there might problem with your class.

Comment: I'd stick with using the constant tag in struts.xml

Comment: @Mohan, thanks for the note. I did try accessing Java in-built static members before posting(missed to mention in above notes list) and it works fine. Accessing static members seems to be problem within my code. But, as I had mentioned in #4 point, I tried accessing static members from class in different package. But, it still does not work.

Comment: @Sannidhi post your class and how you are accessing it.

Comment: Sorry can't do that for confidentiality reasons. That's why I had to use example. Otherwise, I understand posting etiquette. Nonetheless, it's so strange. I had accessed many, many times earlier without any problem. Wonder what's going wrong this time...

Comment: I'm asking original code, http://sscce.org/

Comment: Thanks again for being on it. Updated OP with code.

Comment: @Inject(value="allowStaticMethodAccess", required=false)
    public void setAllowStaticMethodAccess(String allowStaticMethodAccess) {
        this.allowStaticMethodAccess = "true".equalsIgnoreCase(allowStaticMethodAccess);
    }

Attach struts2 source find the above method in class ValueStackFactory and identify whether it's injecting proper value or not.